# Kotlin FlatMap && Recursion

Tags: kotlin

I have a data structure which is a tree. Each Item has children, and they may have children etc:

```
class NavigationItem(
    val title: String,
    val parent: NavigationItem?
) {
    val children: MutableList<NavigationItem> = mutableListOf()
    val isLeaf: Boolean
        get() = children.count() == 0

    val allChildren: List<NavigationItem>
        get() = children.flatMap {
            it.allChildren
        }
}
```

I assumed the `allChildren` synthetic property would traverse the graph, mapping into it's children the  `allChildren` property and go all the way through.

This is not what is happening:

```
@Test
fun testAllChildrenProperty() {
    val root = NavigationItem("Root", null).apply {
        children.add(NavigationItem("Level 1", this))
        children.add(NavigationItem("Level 1", this))
    }
    assertEquals(2 ,root.allChildren.count())
}
```

This unit test fails -- we are just getting an empty list for allChildren. Can anyone explain A) what flatMap in kotlin does and B) What should I be using instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding of the `flatMap` function seems correct, and your use of recursion looks fine. The problem is that although you recurse through all the children, you never actually add any of them to the returned list!

How about this?

```
val allChildren: List<NavigationItem>
    get() = children + children.flatMap { it.allChildren }
```

Note the inclusion of the `children +`, which ensures each child is itself added to the returned list as well as all of its children.

You would need to add some more complex logic if there's a possibility of cycles.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly right! In some other languages , `flatMap` returns an immutable copy of the existing list with the transform applied. I thought that `children +` was implied -- thank you for clarifying!

Comment: Kotlin's `flatMap` is described at https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flat-map.html

It transforms each element into a list, then flattens the results into a single list. It's equivalent to `.map{ ... }.flatten()`.